Does Azure Cosmos Gremlin Supports Transaction Management?
Im trying to achieve transaction management in cosmos gremlin. Like i should be able to create some  nodes and edges in a single transaction, if one of the operation fails the entire transaction should be discarded, like in sql terms commit and rollback. Would i be able to achieve that ?
I tried using DriverRemoteConnection from gremlin driver, which seems to have commit and rollback,
but i cant run any queries using connection.submit(), because this strictly uses Bytecode traversal, which is an unsupported feature of cosmos gremlin https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin/support#unsupported-features.
im using node gremlin package
export const connection : driver.DriverRemoteConnection = new driver.DriverRemoteConnection(
  endpoint,
  {
    authenticator,
    traversalsource: 'g',
    rejectUnauthorized: true,
    mimeType: 'application/vnd.gremlin-v2.0+json',
  }
);

const query = "g.addV('TEST').property('id', 'test').property('partitionKey', 'test').property('name', 'test')";
await connection.open();
const res1 = await connection.submit(query) // fails here saying 'Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Bytecode''
await connection.commit();

So, i changed my approach little bit using process.traversal from gremlin package
const tx = process.traversal().withRemote(connection).tx();
  const g = tx.begin();
  const res1 = await g.addV('VMER').property('id', '2').property('partitionKey', '2').iterate();
  Logger.info('Query executed successfully', res1);
  await tx.commit();

this fails with below error
Stack: ResponseError: Server error: 
[2024-10-29T10:26:46.172Z] 
[2024-10-29T10:26:46.172Z] ActivityId : 8cfb0fcf-7ae1-42c5-9759-d1aa7b23f984
[2024-10-29T10:26:46.172Z] ExceptionType : GraphMalformedException
[2024-10-29T10:26:46.172Z] ExceptionMessage : 
[2024-10-29T10:26:46.172Z]      Gremlin Malformed Request: Unsupported request operation: 'bytecode'.
[2024-10-29T10:26:46.173Z]      GremlinRequestId : e1dda306-ac20-454f-a9c0-7c075c75923b
[2024-10-29T10:26:46.173Z]      Context : global
[2024-10-29T10:26:46.173Z]      GraphInterOpStatusCode : MalformedRequest
[2024-10-29T10:26:46.173Z]      HResult : 0x80131500

Any suggestions?

As mentioned in the official Azure Cosmos DB Gremlin API documentation, transactions are unfortunately not supported.
Cosmos DB docs stating transactions aren't supported
See link below for reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin/support?source=recommendations#unsupported-features

Azure Cosmos DB Gremlin does not support Transaction Management as of today:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin/support?source=recommendations#unsupported-features
However, you can post your feedback over Azure Cosmos DB feedback channel to get this feature created if upvoted and prioritized by the team:
https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/3002b3be-0d25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0858
